# Is it enough if $g$ is injective for $g ◦ f$ to be injective?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This question came to mind when I got the following question:

> Let $f : X → Y$ and $g : Y → Z$ be functions. Show that if $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then so is $g ◦ f$

But this got me wondering, isn't enough for just $g$ to be injective? We have $g ◦ f=g(f(x))$ so $g$ is just taking a certain input, by definition 
 $g$ can't be injective unless it gives a unique output for **every** unique input, so regardless what $f(x)$ results in it's still an input, and it falls under "every input" so $g ◦ f$ should be injective regardless of the what $f(x)$ is.

Note: I know that the question doesn't imply what I am saying is wrong, in fact, it says nothing about it, so this got me wondering.

Comment: Take $f$ to be CONSTANT, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Injectivity means that for two different inputs you get two different outputs. If you now take $f$ non-injective, then there exists two different inputs $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. But then naturally also $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$ since you are taking twice the same argument and applying $g$.

This is equivalent to $(g\circ f)(x_1)=(g\circ f) (x_2)$: hence $g\circ f$ cannot be injective.

Thus $f$ being injective is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $g\circ f$ to be injective

Comment: Thank you! it's all clear now. I understand what it means for a function to be injective, sorry if I explained it in a bad way. Your answer made everything clear

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help

Answer (score 2):

Consider the constant map $f:\Bbb N \rightarrow  \Bbb N, n \mapsto 1$ and take $g = id_{\Bbb N}: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$.

$g$ is certainly injective, but $gf = f$ definitely is **not**.